# @Value isn't working on particular @Configuration class on Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

Hi I have been making spring boot project which have 2 of datasource.
I want to use those datasources properties' value from application.yml file and
so that I configured @Configuration Class on our project.

But, even if both of Configuration class was set same way, @Value annotation isn't working on the OracleConfig.class.

I tested related oracle setting which wrote on application.yml file is working on the HiveConfig.class and I confirmed that.

how can I inject value to OracleConfig.class :( ,,,

> I currently strongly doubt OracleConfig.class was working before @Value annotation or other Beans had been initialized.
> should I configure order about bean creation process or (is that make sense)force that OracleConfig.java's @Bean will be created after injection of @Value?

HiveConfig.class

```
@Configuration
public class HiveConfig {

    @Value("${hive.custom.use}")
    private boolean useCustomHive;
    @Value("${hive.custom.some-of-setting}")
    private String SomeOfSetting;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "hive.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource dataSourceHive() throws Exception {
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();

        if (useCustomHive){
            
            hikariDataSource.SetSomeOfSetting(SomeOfSetting);
        }

        return hikariDataSource;
    }
```

OracleConfig.class

```
@Configuration
public class OracleConfig {

    @Value("${oracle.custom.use}")
    private boolean useCustomOracle;
    @Value("${oracle.custom.some-of-setting}")
    private String SomeOfSetting;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oracle.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource dataSourceOracle() throws Exception {
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();

        if (useCustomOracle){
            hikariDataSource.SetSomeOfSetting(SomeOfSetting);
        }

        return hikariDataSource;
    }
```

application.yml (this values(oracle and hive) can read from HiveConfig.class via @Value)

```
oracle:
  custom:
    use:true
    some-of-setting: str
hive:
  custom:
    use:true
    some-of-setting: str
```

Comment: the dash `-` should be avoided, please have a try?

Comment: thank you very much lei yang! I just try that but I encountered same issue. but thank you for advice !

Comment: The hyphen not the problem I using it always without any problem.

Comment: can you try to replace .yml with .application for test only and try again?

Comment: Did you try to log values on `dataSourceOracle` bean creation?

Comment: thank you all!  
I tried to log values and I confirmed values was null on OracleConfig.class!  the other side, every values was injected on HiveConfig.class

Comment: The yml you provided has syntax error. Please provide the actual yml. Or a yml that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: thank you for commnet samabcde ! I updated yml and I tested that ymls content can  read from HiveConfig.java. So I think currently my yml syntax isn't have problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with constructor injection? See if this works.

```
private boolean useCustomHive;
private String SomeOfSetting;
    
HiveConfig (@Value("${hive.custom.use}") boolean useCustomHive, @Value("${hive.custom.some-of-setting}") String SomeOfSetting) {
        this.useCustomHive = useCustomHive;
        this.SomeOfSetting = SomeOfSetting;
}
```